# Most efficient LINQ result for Contains() query

Tags: c#, efficiency, linq

I currently use the following:

```
var result = list.Union(otherList).SelectMany(l => l.children).ToList()

foreach(var child in lotsOfChildren){
    something = result.Contains(child)
}
```

I only use `result` for querying if the list contains items, using `result.Contains(x)`.

This look to be inefficient to me, as, presumably, `Contains()` has to enumerate the entire (static) list each time, to check if an item is contained.

I noticed `ToDictionary()` and `ToLookup()` extension methods, however both these require a key to be defined, which is unnecessary.

I guess what I'm really looking for is a `ToHashSet()` sort of thing - would I have to create this manually, as in `.ToLookup(c => c.GetHashCode, c => c)`?  Or is there a built in method I'm missing? **Or**, alternatively, is this something the compiler will optimise, and I don't need to care about.

Comment: I would usually use ToDictionary for this. Isn't there a childID field you can use as a key?

Comment: @Ryan: Not specifically, but I presume GetHashCode() is much the same. Thanks

Comment: Unless your lists contain many duplicates, it's probably more efficient to do a Concat.SelectMany.Any/FirstOrDefault. Union and ToList require you to iterate the entire collection. The others are lazy (IIRC) and will only traverse as needed to find your target.

Comment: @Telastyn: Apologies, I've misunderstood - you might be on to something there. I was using the `ToList` for efficiency, but it doesn't seem to be required. list and otherList could be 99% equivalent, which is why I was using Union - which is lazy, isn't it?

Comment: @chris - eh, you are right.  I took a peek in reflector and it is indeed lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trivially define an extension method for `ToHashSet` if that's what you're looking for.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source);
    }
}
```

You should now be able to use it in your original example:

```
var result = list.Union(otherList).SelectMany(l => l.children).ToHashSet()

foreach (var child in lotsOfChildren)
{
    something = result.Contains(child)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is of course nicer that my `ToLookup()` type thing. I was curious if there was a more natural way around this, but if this is the best there is, I'll go with it.